# Slow Response and System Lag

Tags: performance

Recently my computer has been responding slowly.  It was fine few days ago, but now it always lags.
I need to find the cause.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you installed any new drivers?

Comment: I removed a dvd drive ..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some troubleshooting ideas :

First, run this command :

```
sudo apt-get install htop iotop
```

- Start a terminal, in it run `htop`
- Start another terminal, in it run `iotop`
- Start another terminal, it it run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`

Wait until the lag occurs, then look at your three terminals :

- The first one will tell you if a process is hogging the processor
- The second one will tell you if your hard disk is being thrashed by a process.
- The third one will tell you if an event has occurred regarding your hardware.

Comment: Thanks,the kernel log says :Buffer I/O error on device sda5, logical block 28279025

Comment: Sounds like you have a disk error on sda5.  Type `df` to get information about where/what this drive is (if you don't know).  Look at the "mounted on" column.  You may have to backup/re-format/restore that hard disk.  (And don't forget to vote up/accept useful answers - thanks!)